# Import R library caret namespace load failed with Jupyter notebook

Tags: r, anaconda, jupyter-notebook, conda, r-caret

I am running R on Anaconda Jupyter notebook and have installed the `caret` package using the `conda` command:

```
conda install -c r r-caret
```

I have Googled some ways to solve it but they didn't work. How can I solve it?

Below is the error message when I execute `library(caret)`:

> Warning message:
>   "package 'caret' was built under R version 3.3.2"
>   Error: package or namespace load failed for 'caret'
>   Traceback:
>
> 1. library(caret)
> 2. stop(gettextf("package or namespace load failed for %s", sQuote(package)), 
>      .     call. = FALSE, domain = NA)

Comment: What version of R are you running? What version of `caret` is installed?

Comment: this command works in my Jupyter notebook `install.packages("caret",repos = "http://cran.us.r-project.org")`. It will be nice to see what are all the ways you tried so far, so that people won't be telling you to do the same steps.